# Is there a universal symbol for Hinduism?

Tags: symbolism, om, symbols

I have come across many symbols like ॐ , Swastika , Yantra and Lord Shiva's Trident that are generally associated with Hinduism.

Just like the cross represents Christianity or crescent represents Islam, is there any universal symbol for Hinduism?

Comment: Just for your information : ॐ , Swastika are in many other religion with slight different shapes.

Comment: ॐ is considered as the only Symbol for representation of Bramha and Hinduism

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aum ॐ is considered as the Bramha Naad the first naad or sound made after the creation this was considered to be made out of the Big Bang Explosion (HiranyaGarbha(golden Cosmic Egg) Expanding).Scientifically you can think it as the CMB (Cosmic Microwave Background radation) left as traces after the Incident of Big Bang. As Aum is complete in itself and the first naad after creation it is also considered as Mantra Raaj (king of all mantras) as Mantras are the made out of naad (vibes or energy waves) , ॐ is Sampurna Naad (whole naad). That's why ॐ is not only a symbol for hinduism but for everything in this universe , it contains the whole universe in itself ,it is the universe itself not just a `universal symbol` ,and talking about Sanatan (hindu) Dharma it is the one which talks only about supreme truth, so we have taken veda vaani (word of vedas) to make ॐ our universal symbol(vedas depict aum as the Bramha Naad).

Comment: Bramha naad or Sampurna naad? You are throwing around a lot of bombastic words, but reading closely, I can't see much sense. So Aum is the sound of creation. How does that mean it contains the whole universe?

Comment: The sound(vibrations and energy fluctuations) at the beginning created everything that is if you see the Big bang theory closely you will see that in very small time gap's after collision there was the creation of fundamental particles as we see it today check this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_the_universe that's why aum is depicted as sampurna or bramha naad.

Comment: You should edit your answer to make it more clearer, point by point. Also, if you can give English meanings to Sanskrit words like "Sampurna" etc, it would be easier to understand for people who might not be Indians.

Answer (score 2):

ॐ, is the actual symbol, others are derivatives. The ॐ represents 'OMKAR' the supreme entity, defined as 'OM KE AKAR WALA', looking like ॐ .

Comment: What in the world does "OM KE AKAR WALA" mean?  What language is it?

Comment: Its hindi, just to put in description, in conjuction with 'shaped like OM'